# How to prevent CTS from toggling each time a tty is opened or closed?

Tags: tty, serial-port, stty

Each time I open() or close() a `tty` device file, the `RTS` line of the port is toggled off for a moment. This seems to happen even when hardware flow control is disabled with `raw -crtscts`.

Is there any way to tell Linux to not toggle the `RTS` line when opening and closing a tty device file?

Answer (score 4):

There is a flag called `HUPCL`:

> If this bit is set, a modem disconnect is generated when all processes
>   that have the terminal device open have either closed the file or
>   exited.

A "modem disconnect" apparently involves toggling the RTS line, because once that flag is disabled, the behavior goes away regardless of the `CRTSCTS` flag setting.

Here is the `stty` command I executed...

```
stty -F /dev/tty0 1000000 raw clocal -hupcl -echo
```